# Disable Uplay overlay on Steam

Tags: steam, ubisoft-connect, assassins-creed-odyssey

I am trying to play Assassin's creed Odyssey on Ubuntu 18 with Proton 5.13-4 on Steam. The game is running but a balloon asking to `shift+f2` to open Uplay is constantly on the top right corner of the screen. If I click do `shift+f2`, Uplay overlay opens up, but I am unable to close it. The game becomes stuck at that point and just crashes.

Can I disable this Uplay nonsense in steam? I tried out adding `-uplay_steam_mode` as a launch option as suggested by one of the Ubisoft Fourm (which I can't find anymore) but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

had the same problem and found a workaround: just start the game and press shift+F2, then disable all notification types, crash the game and restart... should be fine now :)

Comment: Damn, I can't try it out now because I got so annoyed that I returned the game.  Thanks a lot anyway!